# How to take users session screen shot using C#

Tags: windows-services, screenshot

I want to capture all users screens which are connected to my Machine. So how can I do that?

I want to create a windows service which capture users screen.

Thanks 
Laxmilal

Comment: How exactly are these users screens connected to your machine? Remote Desktop? VNC? Or do you mean multiple, physical monitors attached to one computer? What language are you writing this service in?

Comment: These users will connect using Remote Desktop.  I am using C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Windows Terminal Service (WTS) API. This is what you need to do:
1. Use Local system as your system service account. Other accounts will not work.
2. Call WTSOpenServer, then using WTSEnumerateSessions retrieve list of sessions
3. You will get list of WTS_SESSION_INFO structures. Each item there represents sessions. You are only interested in sessions where State is WTSActive.
4. In a loop call CreateProcessAsUser for each session you identified in previous step. Specify sessionId from the WTS_SESSION_INFO structure you have for the session. The name of the process to run would be your favorite screen capture utility. I did not use any of those, but quick search on internet turns up few options.