# Capture the active window to jpg using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, screenshot, multiple-users

I am creating a Windows Application that capture the all users session details.

I want to track that how many users are connected with my machine using RDP session. Want to log all their activity with screen shot.

So I would like to know how can I capture the active screen. I tried 'RUNAS' but its show me current screen shot where I run. I am able to use user's application data but not get Actual screen.

I also tried LogonUser, CreateProcessAsUser but not getting actual point. So please let me know how can I do it ?

I used 'cassia' google library to list all the current logged user.

Thanks
Laxmilal

Comment: As an aside: JPEGs for screen captures [are kind of bad](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take users session screen shot using C#
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489915/how-to-take-users-session-screen-shot-using-c) by the same author?

Comment: Are you trying to capture a desktop from a session that you're not running in?

Comment: Can you run a process when an user logs on, from startup for example?

Comment: Are you sure it is allowed by law? With german law it is not allowed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be far easier to cause your application to startup in the user's session when they log into the machine, and then monitor the user session its already in.  The problems inherent in syncronizing several instances of your running application (one per user logged in) are much easier to solve then the problems involved in having an application punch through windows user sessions and run code in several different sessions at once (and then synchronize it all anyway).